# Cramped up in the timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, timeline

Yesterday, the timeline would have looked like this:

[image: No border between the rows of related review events.]

Today, I went to check the timeline of a post, and this is what I saw:

[image: Related review event rows now have borders between them and there seems to be less padding so text is closer together.]

…and it just instantly made me very tired.

Now, it's not only cramped up. Multiple "red" events are harder to tell apart. It's not obvious if the "Edit x 1" belongs to the line above or below it.

So, **yet again**, I spent time fixing a UI change on my own system by fiddling with CSS and user styles. This was time taken away from actually doing something useful on Stack Overflow (I'm no CSS guru, so it's really a lot of fiddling on my part).

Taken together, all of these recent changes to the UI (User Interface) are, in my opinion, demotivating. I'm starting to feel frustrated that these changes are rolled out with minimal testing, and it's starting to feel like busy work for me to fix them on my end.

I didn't really review today. I don't even feel like going back doing it tomorrow.

I'm not trying to be mean, and I do appreciate *good* changes, but it does feel like stuff is pushed without being tested or reviewed.

Please revert it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I’m working on behalf of the design system to ship some improvements to tables that will make them fully responsive (traditionally a pretty tough problem in the ol’ CSS world), and more accessible. In this case, this means applying overrides to the `td` instead of the `tr`. As you can imagine, Stack Overflow is a pretty big codebase, with many different applications of tables. Some entire layouts are built with tables, complicating things even further.

We’re going to revert these changes for now and try to scope them to *just* the tables that need to be responsive. But here’s the problem, *every* table needs to be responsive. It’s tricky. Product design is tricky.

This is why we have version control. We have *some* visual regression testing, but that assumes we have properly-formed markup, and often only tests scenarios that are closer to ideal than reality.

We’ll get it fixed up. Enjoy your weekend!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I almost can't wait :) (P.S. I plan to post about the [over sized blue boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXXGQ.png) telling me what I can't review in the review overview page too. I changed them to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKPDy.png) on my own system)

Comment: @Scratte Related MSE post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351195/make-all-you-need-at-least-2k-3k-reputation-to-review-banners-equally-wide

Comment: @janw Thank you, but that post is **so** not focusing on the right thing ;)

Comment: Oh, my bad. It's caused by a userscript. Not your fault. I'm going to remove the comment.